# Canvas image leaves weird trail when moving left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I have an [HTML5 Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) where I need to move 2 copies of main object to right and left. Right side seems to be working fine, but left one starts to leave weird greenish trail. [jSfiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/hvftb12y/)

Here is the code. Assignment requires me to write word using various canvas shapes and also frame it into 3 different cubes. I think I missed something ad can't really figure it out. Any help is appreciated

```
var c = document.getElementById("cId");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    var cWidth = c.width;
    var cHeight = c.height;

    var xOff = 1;

    var direction = 1;

    function playAnimation() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);

        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(xOff, 0);
        drawName();
        ctx.restore();

        ctx.save();

        ctx.translate(-1*xOff, 0);
        drawName();
        ctx.restore();

        ctx.save();
        drawName();
        ctx.restore();

        xOff++;

        window.requestAnimationFrame(playAnimation);
    }

    function fDrawRect() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.rect(5, 5, 80, 60);
        ctx.fillRect(5, 5, 80, 60);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.rect(85, 5, 80, 60);
        ctx.fillRect(85, 5, 80, 60);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
        ctx.rect(165, 5, 80, 60);
        ctx.fillRect(165, 5, 80, 60);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function draw(x, y, xTo, yTo, color) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth= 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle=color;
        ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        ctx.lineTo(xTo,yTo);
        ctx.stroke();

    }

    function drawName() {
        //Draw rect around
        fDrawRect();
        //L
        draw(10, 10, 10, 60, "black");
        draw(10, 60, 30, 60, "black");
        //A
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(60, 25, 15, 1*Math.PI, 0);
        ctx.stroke();
        draw(45, 25, 45, 60, "black");
        draw(75, 25, 75, 60, "black");
        draw(45, 35, 75, 35, "black");
        //U
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(90, 45);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(105, 75, 125, 45);
        ctx.stroke();
        draw(90, 45, 90, 10, "black");
        draw(125, 45, 125, 10, "black");
        //R
        draw(140, 10, 140, 60, "black");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(140, 25, 15, 1.5*Math.PI, 0.5*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        draw(140, 40, 155, 60, "black");
        //I
        draw(170, 10, 170, 60, "black");
        //S
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(210, 10);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(170, 10, 250, 60, 190, 60);
        ctx.stroke();

    }
    ctx.translate(450, 150);
    //drawName();
    playAnimation();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

When you attempt to clear the canvas in the beginning of `playAnimation` (using `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight)`), you don't clear the entire area visible in the canvas.

**Proof:** If you draw a rect to cover the area you clear in `playAnimation`, you see that it does not start in the upper left corner like it should ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46n14ksw/)).

**The reason** it does not work is this line, that translates the context once before you start rendering:

```
ctx.translate(450, 150);
```

When you remove it, you see that the the entire visible area is cleared ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aLsd0ur7/)). However, now you don't get the name in the middle of the canvas.

## Solution

The solution is to do the translation at the beginning of each `playAnimation()`, and to undo the translation at the end of the function ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5hz4a5h/)).

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Really dumb mistake

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the canvas in your `fDrawRect` function:

```
    function fDrawRect() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); //Clear canvas
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.rect(5, 5, 80, 60);
        ctx.fillRect(5, 5, 80, 60);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.rect(85, 5, 80, 60);
        ctx.fillRect(85, 5, 80, 60);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
        ctx.rect(165, 5, 80, 60);
        ctx.fillRect(165, 5, 80, 60);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
```

Comment: Why is it not enough to clear a rect the size of the entire canvas at the beginning of each `playAnimation()`?

Comment: Hey, thanks, it fixed trailing, but now only object is moving to left, right one does not work. https://jsfiddle.net/av7tazmy/1/

Comment: @ArneHugo because `playAnimation` is only called once, the canvas needs clearing each time it is re drawn

Comment: @Kirdeika the image only moves left in your original fiddle

Comment: @DNKROZ `playAnimation` is the function that is called again and again to render each frame, so it's not called just once. See 
 `window.requestAnimationFrame(playAnimation);`.

Comment: @DNKROZ in original post it moves to both sides (ctx.translate(xOff, 0) - moves it to right by 1, ctx.translate(-1*xOff, ) - moves it to left same amount by -1). After I added _clearRect_ in my _fDrawRect_ function it stopped moving to right, only to the left. Or I am missing something?

Comment: @Kirdeika sorry you're right.. I opened the fiddle on a long thin monitor and din't realise half of the animation was cut off! haha

Comment: @DNKROZ all okay! Maybe do you know how to solve this problem?