# Html5 canvas animation leaves a trail

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a little game to play around with canvas. I've decided to go for **Flappy Bird** as there are plenty of examples online. My goal was to make the game "responsive" for all devices. If you open it in a mobile or whichever screen, you should be able to play it normally.

For this purpose I drew a background image within the canvas that will adapt the height to the screen's height and repeat it through the x-axis.

[image: Flappy Bird]

The issue I'm having is that, when I animate the bird, this one leaves a trail behind it.

As like so:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu0Vzm.png]

An easy fix would be clearing the canvas as explained in this post:

[Canvas image leaves weird trail when moving left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554402/canvas-image-leaves-weird-trail-when-moving-left)

But it isn't possible because of the way I'm painting my background (I paint it once and repaint it if it resizes).

> ## Question
>
> How do I avoid this image trail with a static background? Is it maybe possible to have like a false static background that doesn't need to be repainted?
>
> I obviously want to do it in the canvas, without needing to have an image in the html.

This is the code with the main functionality so that you can take a look:

```js
const cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

cvs.style.height = "100vh";
cvs.style.width = "100vw";

var bird = new Image();
var bg = new Image();

bird.src = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/prntPuix7QxlhKXx6IBtTxv7PrdEJtmzFJ4mopScNS1_klze86BVNy3PqHbQn2UQ4JyJdix3XQ=w128-h128-e365";
bg.src = "https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/bg_5.png";

let gravity = 1;
birdPositionY = 10;
birdPositionX = 50;

const draw = () => {
  ctx.drawImage(bird, birdPositionX, birdPositionY);

  birdPositionY += gravity;
  birdPositionX += 3;

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
};

const resizeCanvas = () => {
  const {
    width,
    height
  } = cvs.getBoundingClientRect();
  cvs.height = height;
  cvs.width = width;

  let x = 0,
    y = 0;
  while (x < cvs.width && y < cvs.height) {
    ctx.drawImage(bg, x, y, 360, cvs.height);
    x += bg.width;
  }
};

bg.onload = () => {
  resizeCanvas();
};

window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas, false);

draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Flappy Bird</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
  <style>
    html {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    canvas {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it did make sense!

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw your background on a canvas that you will keep off-screen, then draw this canvas every frame on your visible one before you draw your moving parts.

```js
const cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
// our backround canvas that we won't append in the doc ("off-screen")
const background = cvs.cloneNode();
const bg_ctx = background.getContext('2d');

cvs.style.height = "100vh";
cvs.style.width = "100vw";

var bird = new Image();
var bg = new Image();

bird.src = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/prntPuix7QxlhKXx6IBtTxv7PrdEJtmzFJ4mopScNS1_klze86BVNy3PqHbQn2UQ4JyJdix3XQ=w128-h128-e365";
bg.src = "https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/bg_5.png";

let gravity = 1;
birdPositionY = 10;
birdPositionX = 50;

const draw = () => {
  // first draw the background canvas
  ctx.drawImage(background, 0,0);
  // then your persona
  ctx.drawImage(bird, birdPositionX, birdPositionY);

  birdPositionY += gravity;
  birdPositionX += 3;

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
};

const resizeCanvas = () => {
  const {
    width,
    height
  } = cvs.getBoundingClientRect();
  // resize both canvases
  cvs.height = background.height = height;
  cvs.width = background.width = width;

  let x = 0,
    y = 0;
  while (x < cvs.width && y < cvs.height) {
    // draw on the off-screen canvas
    bg_ctx.drawImage(bg, x, y, 360, cvs.height);
    x += bg.width;
  }
};

bg.onload = () => {
  resizeCanvas();
  draw();
};

window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Flappy Bird</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
  <style>
    html {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    canvas {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much @Kaiido

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just call `resizeCanvas` in your draw loop to redraw the background.

EDIT: Apparently that does not work. Another option is just drawing it in the draw loop like this:

```
const draw = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height)
  let x = 0, y = 0;
  while (x < cvs.width && y < cvs.height) {
    ctx.drawImage(bg, x, y, 360, cvs.height);
    x += bg.width;
  }

  ctx.drawImage(bird, birdPositionX, birdPositionY);

  birdPositionY += gravity;
  birdPositionX += 3;

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
};
```

Edit: That did not work either. The other option would be to make two canvases and overlap them with one drawing the background and one drawing the bird.

Comment: It doesn't, I've tried that as well but it freezes the screen

Comment: It's the exact same code but in another place, so the result is the same. You can test it in the snippet

Comment: Sorry. The other option might be to create two canvases and have one draw the background and the other one draw the bird.